# Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Keep getting the following error message in React Native, really don't understand where it is coming from

> Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted.
> This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application.
> Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};`
> class property with the desired state in the ConnectionMqtt component.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived.bind(this)
}

componentDidMount() {
    const conn = new ConnectionMqtt();
    conn.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use setState in the constructor since the component is not mounted yet. In this case clickMe() method calls setState().
Instead, initialize the state directly. Like,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Don't call this.setState() here!
    this.state = { counter: 0 };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

example if from https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor